# angular Js: Array.lenght property gives undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a REST call which gives me an array of object as `[object, object, object]`

but when I try to print the lenght its giving me undefined.

```
$http.get('/admin/getDoctorsFromFacility/' + sharedService.getFacilityId())
    .success(function(doctorData) {
        console.log(doctorData);
        console.log(doctorData.lenght);
        $scope.doctors = doctorData;
    });
```

Comment: what did you get for console.log(doctorData)?

Comment: I misspelled length it seems. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `length` property name

```
console.log(doctorData.lenght);
```

convert this

```
doctorData.lenght
```

to this

```
doctorData.length
```

Comment: Sorry but it looks the same

Comment: what `console.log(doctorData);` is printing ?

Comment: [object, object, object]

Comment: Oh i got it I misspelled it . Thanks a lot

Comment: Then it's an object array. Select an individual object, and inspect it.

Comment: @sacDahal you are welcome :) don't forget to mart it accepted :)